# Dynamic antd form intialValue set issue while use "valuePropName: 'defaultValue'"

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am building dynamic form using antd form getfielddecorator from JSON and successfully created it. But When i am typing into into Input control, Whole component re-rendered on every time. So i have followed this issue: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/13063 and fixed it.

```
<FormItem className="ant col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12" label={'name'} >
        {getFieldDecorator('name', { trigger: 'onBlur',valuePropName: 'defaultValue', initialValue:data.name})
            (<Input type='text' autoComplete="off" onBlur={this.onChange}  />)
        }
</FormItem>
```

BUT I have faced another issue for bind Input value using initialValue.

For example:

State of data:

1) In inital load

data: {
    name : ''
}

2) After fetched data from Ajax Call,

data: {
    name: 'abcd'
}

After bind, On UI - it bind only blank value (''), rather than 'abcd'.

Ant Version: "antd": "^3.13.2"

So Can you please provide any help?

Comment: Try setting explicitly the input value with `setFieldsValue` on the `form` prop in your ajax resolver.

Comment: I have already tried to set the value using this.props.form.setFieldsValue but still not worked. When I removed this coding line trigger: 
('onBlur',valuePropName: 'defaultValue' )  from getFieldDecorator than it works fine. But it re-rendering component again in each character typing.